# How to make ggplot2 run with 2 layers?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's my code:

```
tmp <- data.frame(t_year = rnorm(100,0,1),
                  labs =  c(rep("Linear",50), rep("Spline",50)),
                  STUDY_PARTICIPANT_ID = rep(seq(1,50),2),
                  logpsa = rnorm(100,0.5,1),
                  mypredict = rnorm(100,1,2))


p <- ggplot(tmp) + 
       geom_line(aes(t_year,
                     mypredict,
                     group = as.factor(labs),
                     color = as.factor(labs))) + 
       geom_line(aes(t_year,
                     logpsa,
                     group = STUDY_PARTICIPANT_ID,
                     color = STUDY_PARTICIPANT_ID))
```

It only runs with either one of the `geom_line()`, but it doesn't when I tried to plot both. I was hoping it would treat them separately, but I don't think that's the case. Does anyone have any suggestion? I originally used `geom_smooth()` for the fitted lines, but I was unable to add a legend at the side of the ggplot. Therefore, I got the fitted values and put them in the dataset and was just going to plot them with `geom_line()`. All I wanted was just a label for my linear fit line and my spline. The data here doesn't show the trend, but it will give you the error messages that I was getting. Thank you for your patience with my first post.

Comment: You can't map an aesthetic like `color` twice. You only get one color scale for the whole plot. I think you probably mean to use faceting in addition to color, but it's impossible to help much more than that without a reproducible example.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.  To help make a reproducible example, you can use   `reproduce(<your data>)` . Instructions are here: http://bit.ly/SORepro   -  [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://bit.ly/SORepro)